# Creating Protobuf C++ files from .proto file in Android.mk

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, protocol-buffers, android-make

I am trying to get to run this simple command inside the Android.mk to create .cc and .hh files out of the comm.proto file given below, which is needed for my c++ library to be built.

```
$(shell $(LOCAL_PATH)/ext/bin/protoc 
        --proto_path=$(LOCAL_PATH)/comm 
        --cpp_out=$(LOCAL_PATH)/comm 
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/comm/comm.proto )
```

I have all the necessary files kept in the directory structure as mentioned in my command.

**My Questions are:**

1.Is it a valid way to run commands inside Android.mk?

2.Also, once this works is there a way I can make sure that this command is run only when comm.proto file has changed?(Any timestamp  based approach)